# I want to close my drop-menu on same button click it opened with but i use keep-open

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I want to have the below code working when not clicking on `#dropMenuLogin`.

```
$("body:not(#dropdownMenuLogin)").click(function(){
  $('.keep-open').on({
      "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = false; },
      "click":             function() { this.closable = false; },
      "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
});
});
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: `a:not(#b)` is the inverse of `a#b`.  It does not denote a child selector.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for your time and answer. I don't understand i am saying click when body but dont execute the code when `#dropdownMenuLogin` is clicked. So this is not correct? How do i need to do it? I want it to close when `#dropdownMenuLogin` is clicked. ELSE the dropdown needs to stay open.

Comment: Is the id `dropdownMenuLogin` on the body, or on a child of the body?

Comment: @Taplar My navigation.php which contains `#dropdownMenuLogin` is within the body tag yes. Everything inside the body can be the child of the body. I don't understand sorry

Comment: So it's a **child** of the body.  Re-read what my first comment said.  `body:not(#someId)` is matching against the **body** tag not having that id on it.  It doesn't have anything to do with the children of the body.

Comment: @Taplar So your saying i cant use `body:not(id)` because it is the child of the body? Or dont i understand what you just said :P

Comment: Since the id will never be on the body element, `body:not(#someid)` would always be true, and match the body.

Comment: @Taplar Oh i thought the id could be every ID if it is in a element or not in a elemnt.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just handle it in the callback instead of using a selector

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id === "dropdownMenuLogin") return;
  console.log("not dropdownMenuLogin")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdownMenuLogin">test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. The weird thing is `if(e.target.id === "dropdownMenuLogin") {
    alert(1);}` Doesn't alert i don't understand. It does alert in ELSE.

Comment: What does `e.target.id` give you? make sure it's `dropdownMenuLogin`.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I found out why `<a id='dropdownMenuLogin'>Login</a>` << This works. But NOT this >> `<a id='dropdownMenuLogin' class='nav-link badge no-style-for-badge' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Login<i class='arrow-loginheader down'></i></a>`.I still need to see which element excactly it is what blocks the `target.id`

Comment: `data-toggle='dropdown'` Blocks the `target.id`.

Comment: How can this be fixed i don't know how, i tried everything i can. Do you know how?

Comment: How did it block the target.id? It works fine with your markups

Comment: it just blocks the target if `data-toggle='dropdown' inside the `<a>` tag. What do you mean it works fine with my markups? You tested the code in the comment section?

Comment: I see now that this works `$('a[href="#bla"]').click(function() {alert(1);` it alerts 1 when i click on that. But how do i do something else when its not `href=#bla`?

Comment: Man i am playing with it and it doesnt work. I just want the dropdown-menu to close only when i click on the link which i opened with it

Comment: There is something wrong. I tried it inside codeply.com with someone having an answer with the same output i want. And inside codeply it doesn't close. If i copy the codeply code to my OWN code it DOES close. Maybe due to different bootstrap version i don't know. Must be something like that.....